# Unable to get all the values from JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-10

Table with sample data:

```
create table tbl_jsdata
(
id int,
p_id int,
field_name text,
field_value text 
);

insert into tbl_jsdata values       
(1,101,'Name','Sam'),
(2,101,'City','Dubai'),
(3,101,'Pin','1235'),
(4,101,'Country','UAE'),
(5,102,'Name','Sam'),
(6,102,'City','Dubai'),
(7,102,'Name','Sam Jack'),
(8,102,'Name','Test'),
(9,102,'Name',null);
```

json_agg query:

```
drop table if exists tempJSData;

select p_id,
    json_build_array(json_object_agg(field_name, field_value)) into tempJSData
from tbl_jsdata
group by p_id;
```

Getting Result:

```
select p_id,(json_array_elements(json_build_array)->>'Name')::text Namess
from tempJSData


p_id    Namess
---------------------------------
101     Sam
102
```

Expected Result:

```
p_id    Namess
---------------------------------
101     Sam
102     Sam
102     Sam Jack
102     Test
102
```

Comment: Unrelated: use `jsonb` instead of `json`

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the expected result. Why is `(102, Sam)` not part of the result?

Comment: Btw: `select ... into` is discouraged in favor of the standard compliant `create table .. as select ..`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Ah! Sorry. Forgot to mention that `(102,Sam)` question edited.

Comment: Actually I have created a table which holds the all the data in JSON form which gonna used for reporting purpose and this process done by schedule job which execute the function which inserts the JSON data into the table.

Comment: I think you should use `jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(field_name, field_value))` to create the `tempjsdata` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're not creating an array of `Name`.

If you check your query

```
select p_id,
    json_build_array(json_object_agg(field_name, field_value))
from tbl_jsdata
group by p_id;
```

The result is

```
 p_id |                                      json_build_array
------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  101 | [{ "Name" : "Sam", "City" : "Dubai", "Pin" : "1235", "Country" : "UAE" }]
  102 | [{ "Name" : "Sam", "City" : "Dubai", "Name" : "Sam Jack", "Name" : "Test", "Name" : null }]
(2 rows)
```

Having multiple adjacent entries of the `Name` field. The following `json_array_elements(json_build_array)->>'Name'` will fetch the first entry only. I suggest to create an array based on `p_id` and `field_name` first

```
with array_built as (
    select p_id,field_name,
        array_agg(field_value) field_value
    from tbl_jsdata
    group by p_id, field_name
)
select p_id,
    jsonb_object_agg(field_name, field_value)
from array_built
group by p_id
;
```

The result can be optimised since it creates an array even if there is only one value

```
 p_id |                             jsonb_object_agg
------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  101 | {"Pin": ["1235"], "City": ["Dubai"], "Name": ["Sam"], "Country": ["UAE"]}
  102 | {"City": ["Dubai"], "Name": ["Sam", "Sam Jack", "Test", null]}
(2 rows)
```

But now you can parse it correctly the whole query is

```
select p_id,
    json_build_array(json_object_agg(field_name, field_value)) 
from tbl_jsdata
group by p_id;

select p_id,
    json_build_array(json_object_agg(field_name, field_value)) 
from tbl_jsdata
group by p_id;

with array_built as (
    select p_id,field_name,
        array_agg(field_value) field_value
    from tbl_jsdata
    group by p_id, field_name
), agg as (
select p_id,
    jsonb_object_agg(field_name, field_value) json_doc
from array_built
group by p_id
)

select p_id, jsonb_array_elements(json_doc->'Name')  from agg;
;
```

With the expected result as

```
 p_id | jsonb_array_elements
------+----------------------
  101 | "Sam"
  102 | "Sam"
  102 | "Sam Jack"
  102 | "Test"
  102 | null
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_each_text` to extract the values of your array and in the `WHERE` clause filter only the `key` you want:

```
SELECT p_id,j.value
FROM tempJSData, json_each_text(json_build_array->0) j
WHERE j.key = 'Name';

 p_id |  value   
------+----------
  101 | Sam
  102 | Sam
  102 | Sam Jack
  102 | Test
  102 | 
(5 rows)
```

Note: this query assumes the format of your json is final. If not, consider creating an array of `Name` instead of an array of objects that contain names in it: `name[foo,bar]` instead of `[name:foo,name:bar]`. The answer from Ftisiot makes a pretty good point.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=39744b4ed12deb450d869563ff32858c)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON aggregation is essentially invalid, as you are creating a JSON value where the same key appears more than once. If you had used the recommended `jsonb` data type, the duplicate keys would have been removed.

I think this aggregation makes more sense:

```
create table tempjsdata
as
select p_id,
       jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(field_name, field_value)) as names
from tbl_jsdata
group by p_id
```

The above generates the following result:

```
p_id | names                                                                                       
-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 101 | [{"Name": "Sam"}, {"City": "Dubai"}, {"Pin": "1235"}, {"Country": "UAE"}]                   
 102 | [{"Name": "Sam"}, {"City": "Dubai"}, {"Name": "Sam Jack"}, {"Name": "Test"}, {"Name": null}]
```

Then you can use:

```
select p_id, 
       x.*
from tempjsdata
  cross join lateral (
     select x.item ->> 'Name'
     from jsonb_array_elements(t.names) as x(item)  
     where x.item ? 'Name'
  ) x
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2d7c4ae135ead4fc798fd4c3d1aea9c6)